# how to have a new local array at each level of recursive function

Tags: java, c, arrays, pointers, recursion

I have a recursive function where I am passing an array as a local variable. (I understand that if you pass an array as an argument in a function, only the pointer, ie the starting address of the array gets passed. But my objective is to find a way to overcome all these limitations to work in a purely application point of view.)

At each level of recursion, I am altering the contents of the array and calling the recursive function with this array. What I want is that, when the recursion is over, I want the array at each level to be like how it was when going forward in recursion. At the moment what I observe is that, while coming back in recursion, the array contents remain the same across all calls.

This is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int len = 0;

int main(void)
{
 int a[5] = {0};

 len = sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a);

 fun(a,0);

 return 0;
}

int fun(int a[], int j)
{
 if(j==5)
  return;

 a[j] = j;
 fun(a,j+1);
}
```

This is the output of my gdb trace. As you can see, while going forward, the array contents look like

```
level 0 -{0}
level 1 -{0,1}
level 2 -{0,1,2}
level 3 -{0,1,2,3}
level 4 -{0,1,2,3,4}
```

But while coming back, it's always

```
level 4 -{0,1,2,3,4}
level 3 -{0,1,2,3,4}
level 2 -{0,1,2,3,4}
level 1 -{0,1,2,3,4}
```

I would like my array to look like this while coming back in recursion

```
level 4 -{0,1,2,3,4}
level 3 -{0,1,2,3}
level 2 -{0,1,2}
level 1 -{0,1}
level 0 -{0}
```

gdb trace

```
(gdb) disp *a@5
1: *a@5 = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
(gdb) disp j
2: j = 0
(gdb) s
2: j = 0
1: *a@5 = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
2: j = 0
1: *a@5 = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
fun (a=0x7fffffffdf90, j=1) at main.c:18
2: j = 1
1: *a@5 = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
2: j = 1
1: *a@5 = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
(gdb) s
2: j = 1
1: *a@5 = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
2: j = 1
1: *a@5 = {0, 1, 0, 0, 0}
fun (a=0x7fffffffdf90, j=2) at main.c:18
2: j = 2
1: *a@5 = {0, 1, 0, 0, 0}
2: j = 2
1: *a@5 = {0, 1, 0, 0, 0}
2: j = 2
1: *a@5 = {0, 1, 0, 0, 0}
(gdb) s
2: j = 2
1: *a@5 = {0, 1, 2, 0, 0}
fun (a=0x7fffffffdf90, j=3) at main.c:18
2: j = 3
1: *a@5 = {0, 1, 2, 0, 0}
2: j = 3
1: *a@5 = {0, 1, 2, 0, 0}
2: j = 3
1: *a@5 = {0, 1, 2, 3, 0}
1: *a@5 = {0, 1, 2, 3, 0}
(gdb) s
fun (a=0x7fffffffdf90, j=4) at main.c:18
2: j = 4
1: *a@5 = {0, 1, 2, 3, 0}
2: j = 4
1: *a@5 = {0, 1, 2, 3, 0}
2: j = 4
1: *a@5 = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
fun (a=0x7fffffffdf90, j=5) at main.c:18
2: j = 5
1: *a@5 = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
1: *a@5 = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
(gdb) s
2: j = 5
1: *a@5 = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
2: j = 5
1: *a@5 = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
2: j = 4
1: *a@5 = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
2: j = 3
1: *a@5 = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
2: j = 2
1: *a@5 = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
(gdb) s
2: j = 1
1: *a@5 = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
2: j = 0
1: *a@5 = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
main () at main.c:13
```

EDIT:
 Also, is this the case for other languages, say java as well. I was thinking that in java the concept of pointers does not exists, it saves each array as a local variable for that recursive call alone. But I'm getting the same output as in C.

Code

```
class Hello
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  int[] a = {0,0,0,0,0};
  fun(a,0);

  System.out.println("");
 }

 static void fun(int[] a, int j)
 {
  int i = 0;

  if(j==5)
  {
   for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    System.out.print(a[i]);

   System.out.println("");
   return;
  }

  a[j] = j;
  fun(a,j+1);

  System.out.print("at j=="+j+" : ");
  for(i=0;i<5;i++)
   System.out.print(a[i]);

  System.out.println("");
 }
}
```

Output

```
01234
at j==4 : 01234
at j==3 : 01234
at j==2 : 01234
at j==1 : 01234
at j==0 : 01234
```

Comment: Do not use a function without previous declaration/prototype! This will generate a warning (IMO, it should be an error) since C99. Enable warnings and use at least C99 (better the current standard C11).

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, I'm solving a question where my solution is not working because of this problem. I couldn't post the entire code of the original problem as it digresses from the point. So made this small snippet to convey the point

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, I corrected it in my java program above. Please read my edit.

Comment: Array in java is a reference type. (Copy of the contents of the array are not the be created as value type)

Comment: Since in Java most things have reference semantics almost everything there's in fact a pointer. Just think of `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 1):

Just restore the contents on each call before returning:

```
void fun(int a[], int j) {
    if (j == 5) {
        return;
    }

    int tmp = a[j];
    a[j] = j;
    fun(a, j+1);
    a[j] = tmp;
}
```

Also as mentioned in the comments you shouldn't use a function without previously declaring or defining it. You can declare it with a prototype before `main()`:

```
void fun(int a[], int j);
```

Or just define it altogether before `main()` and you won't need the prototype.

Note: the function doesn't return anything, so the right return type is `void`, not `int`.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Care to clarify? UB where?

Comment: The function returns nothing though it has return type int.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow True - that's what you get when you copy the code from the question. Updated my answer, thanks for noticing.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves, thanks for your comment. It's helpful. But I would like to know if this is the case for other languages, say java as well. I was thinking that in java the concept of pointers does not exists, it saves each array as a local variable for that recursive call alone. But I'm getting the same output as in C. Please clarify and check my edit as well.

Answer (score 0):

> What I want is that, when the recursion is over, I want the array at
>   each level to be like how it was when going forward in recursion.

It can be treated as a value type by wrapping an array by struct.

E.g

```
#include <stdio.h>

int len = 0;

typedef struct  {
    int a[5];
} varType;

void fun(varType v, int i);

int main(void){
    varType v = {0};
    len = sizeof(v.a)/sizeof(*v.a);

    fun(v,0);

    return 0;
}

void fun(varType x, int j){
#if DEBUG
    for(int i=0; i < len; ++i)
        printf("%d ", x.a[i]);
    printf("\n");
#endif
    if(j==5)
        return;

    x.a[j] = j;
    fun(x, j+1);
#if DEBUG
    for(int i=0; i < len; ++i)
        printf("%d ", x.a[i]);
    printf("\n");
#endif

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//something of the form to null out the last element prior to falling out of each recursion

int fun(int a[], int j)
{
    static int i = 0;

    if(j<5){
        a[j] = j;
        i++;//inc on each recursion

        fun(a,j+1);
    }

    i--;//decrement on  falling out of each recursion

    a[i] = 0;//null out the last index

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where is return statement? Please care to add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

As others have hinted at, in most cases it is more convenient and efficient to reuse the same array (as you already are doing when you pass around a reference to it), but instead have each level of the stack "undo" whatever it did to the array before it returns. This will cause the output that you desire (each level sees the array as unchanged when the recursive calls below it complete).

However, since you ask explicitly how to create a new array at each level, here is how you can do precisely that in Java:

Simply change the recursive call to `fun(a, j + 1);` to `fun(Arrays.copyOf(a, a.length), j + 1);`.

The recursion here is really not relevant, if your question is simply how to copy an array (or any object). I am rusty on my C libraries, but there has to be an easy way to copy an array, or you could just write your own copy method in a few lines, simply allocate a new array the same size as the source copy, and then copy elements one by one.